# How to perform prepareForSegueFunction on ViewController load?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to perform a segue when the ViewController loads so it can trigger the `prepareForSegue` function.

I have tried using `performselector` but it does not work. Any suggestions?

```
func doSegue() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "doSegue", sender: nil)
}    
perform(Selector(("doSegue")), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let guest = segue.destination as! WarningTableViewController
    //code
}
```

It says it cannot find a selector named `doSegue`.

Comment: Can you add more information on what exactly are you trying to achieve? why can't you let the system run prepareForSeque at the right moment?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is confusing.
Why there's a `perform(Selector...` there?

Here's a working example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "doSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "doSegue" {
            print("It works")
            // Or call another function, e.g. "doSomethingElse()"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: itWorks]

Also double-check the segue declaration in `Interface Builder`:

[image: ib]

Comment: for some reason it is not working for me. I honestly don't know what's wrong.

Comment: If you could, share your entire Xcode project via GitHub or something. I can try running here. But you should also update your question telling exactly what your code is and the entire error message.